# DataTables warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable

My JS code:

```
function filtre() {
    var status = document.getElementById("filtre").value;
    $.get("users/liste/" + status, function (data) {
        $("#example2_wrapper").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "../admin/users/liste/" + status,
            "aoColumns": [
                {mData: "id"},
                {mData: "name"},
                {mData: "user_level"},
                {mData: "location"},
                {mData: "gender"},
                {mData: "status"},
                {mData: "islem"}
            ]
        });
    });
}
```

İ can't fill data bale with my data. It's type is JSON which is datatable's need. The error is

> DataTables warning: table id=example2_wrapper - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you are initialising table after your first initialisation

try this code

```
function filtre() {
    var status=document.getElementById("filtre").value;
    $.get('users/liste/' + status, function (data) {
        $('#example2_wrapper').DataTable({

            "destroy": true,                

            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "../admin/users/liste/"+status,
            "aoColumns": [
                {mData: "id"},
                {mData: "name"},
                {mData: "user_level"},
                {mData: "location"},
                {mData: "gender"},
                {mData: "status"},
                {mData: "islem"}
            ]
        });
    } );
}
```

so destroy existing table and then reinitialise it

Comment: You're fantastic Thank's a lot:)

Comment: "destroy": true,              only required, thank you